# How type error is occured in this program?

Tags: python

```
import sys

def c(a,b):
    return a/b
def b(a,b):
    return c(a,b)
def a(a,b):
    try:
        d=b(a,b)
        print(f"the answer is {d}")
    except:
        print("unexpected error " , sys.exc_info()[0])

a(2,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hadn't caught the exception and discarded the useful info, you would have known.

`def b(a, b):` is the problem, together with having a local variable `b`: `b` can't be both a function and an integer at the same time. In this case, `b` is an integer (the local parameter variable shadowing the global function), so you're trying to do `d = 2(2, 2)`, which makes no sense.

Either rename the function, or the parameter.